# Make container of elements with margin in-between elements but not the container?

Tags: css, css-float

- Container `#666` has `margin: 20px; overflow: hidden;`.
- Nodes `#333` have `margin: 20px 0 0 20px; float: left;`.

Example, http://jsbin.com/owejal/3/edit or picture:

[image: double margin]

However, the intended result is:

- container with 20px margin,
- children with 20px margin in-between, but not with the container.

[image]

This could be achieved using negative padding (i.e. if container had `padding: -20px 0 0 -20px`), though such thing does not exist.

The **desired result** can be achieved using additional element (http://jsbin.com/owejal/4/), though I am keen to learn whether there is CSS only solution.

Comment: are various widths of the `.group` container something you'd like to account for? For instance, will there always be 3 elements below and 4 above? or would you prefer this to adapt on the fly?

Comment: The number of child elements and their dimensions is unknown in advance.

Comment: To my knowledge this cannot be done in pure css as there is no way for css to know when a child will wrap to a new row

Comment: It seems that you need to define logic which cannot be achieved via pure CSS. Would love to be proven wrong.

Comment: @FrancisKim request you to look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089066/make-container-of-elements-with-margin-in-between-elements-but-not-the-container/18276370#18276370

Answer (score 5):

If you only care about the spacing between the elements, you can discard the pseudo element.  It's only there for the background.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/mucDv

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="group">
  <div class="node"></div>
  <div class="node"></div>
  <div class="node"></div>
  <div class="node"></div>
  <div class="node"></div>
  <div class="node"></div>
  <div class="node"></div>
</div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
.group {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: -10px 0 -10px 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.group:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px; /* 20px instead of 10px due to padding */
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background: #666;
}

.node {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: #333;
  margin: 10px;
}

.foo {
  height: 20px;
  background: #00f;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a little hacky, but how about just hiding the top and left margin areas with some strategically placed pseudo-elements?
http://jsfiddle.net/SUJtd/

```
.foo {height:20px; background:#00f; margin:20px 20px 0;}

.group {overflow:hidden; margin:0 20px 20px 0; background:#666; position:relative;}
.group:before{content:""; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; height:20px; background:#fff;}
.group:after{content:""; position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; width:20px; background:#fff;}

.node {width:100px; height:100px; float:left; background:#333; margin:20px 0 0 20px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

**No extra HTML tag** - but a class change & **No Pseudo elements**

A simple trick which probably should work for you :
http://jsbin.com/owejal/65/edit

Screenshot:

[image]

Will work with all possible number of nodes :)

```
<div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="node"></div>
    <div class="node"></div>
    <div class="node"></div>
    <div class="node"></div>
    <div class="node"></div>
    <div class="node"></div>
    <div class="node"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.group { overflow: hidden; margin: 20px; margin-bottom:0px; /* margin is required */ background: #666; }
.node { width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; background: #333; margin: 0px 20px 20px 0px; /* there must 20px gap between every node, but not the container */ }
.foo { height: 20px; background: #00f; margin: 20px;}
.foo2{
  height:20px;
  background:#00f;
  border-top:20px solid white;
  margin:20px;
  margin-top:-20px;
}
```

Comment: If the container resized so that it *exactly* fits a certain number of children, there is a 20px gap on the right side.  I don't know if this is something the OP wants to avoid.  Also, a white border to simulate the ancestor's background will only work if it is a solid color (ie. no bg images).

Comment: no images have been used here..just saying! the gap on the right side is okay i think from the expected screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't mention resizability as requirement, you could simple use a nth child declaration like in here:

http://jsbin.com/owejal/51/

However, this solution is optimized for fixed widths of parent container, so there should always be 4 elements in a row for example. Nevertheless, its css only.

Answer (score 1):

Change the margin of the node to:

```
.node { margin: 0 20px 20px 0; }
```

See http://jsbin.com/owejal/52/edit. Note that this will still give you extra padding at the bottom, but this is a common issue that isn't easily solved. See http://css-tricks.com/spacing-the-bottom-of-modules/ for various ways to solve this (though in the case you presented, none of these solutions work).

Answer (score -1):

The following CSS will get you the desired result, actually you will still have 2 limitations:

1. If you change the background of body, you need to update the border color for element .foo
2. The inner nodes still have right margin, this is also the case your desired result screen shot (.group can have 5 nodes, but in this solution it will only have 4).

```
.group {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px; /* margin is required */ 
    background: #666;  
}
.node {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: #333;
    margin: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
}
.foo { 
    height: 20px;
    background: #00f;
    margin: 20px; 
}
.group + .foo { 
    height: 20px;
    background: #00f;
    margin: 20px; 
    position: relative;
    top:-40px;
    border-top: 20px solid #fff;
}
```

You can still find the solution [here](http://jsbin.com/owejal/46/edit)

Comment: This solution is already part of the question. See the last paragraph. Furthermore, it says "no additional elements".